# Implementing date_sub() function with intervals with jOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I've been dealing with this since yestertay.

The thing is I am migrating my queries to [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) and I got stuck when I tried to implement this part:

```
select * from table where condition1 and date1 >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 days)
```

Specifically this part of the condition: **date_sub(now(), interval 1 days)** with jOOQ.

So my questions are:

1. Which functions should I use from jOOQ to represent date_sub?
2. How do I implement **interval X days** with jOOQ?

To clarify, the dates are of the type **Timestamp**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The solution:

Being slightly biased towards the Oracle database, jOOQ implements adding / subtracting day intervals simply by using:

```java
// Java
DSL.currentTimestamp().sub(1);
```

The above renders:

```sql
-- Oracle
sysdate - 1

-- MySQL
date_add(current_timestamp(), interval -1 day)
```

Of course, you can also access the [`date_add()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#dateAdd%28org.jooq.Field,%20org.jooq.Field%29) function directly, if you prefer that:

```java
// Java
DSL.dateAdd(DSL.currentTimestamp(), -1);
```

#### Some documentation:

- [The manual's section about date time arithmetic](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/arithmetic-expressions/#N113ED)
- [The manual's section about interval data types](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/reference/reference-data-types/data-types-intervals/)
- [`Field.add()` Javadoc](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#add%28org.jooq.Field%29)
- [`DSL.dateAdd()` Javadoc](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#dateAdd%28org.jooq.Field,%20org.jooq.Field%29)