# JOOQ how to add timestamps and an Integer representing milliseconds together?

Tags: java, sql, timestamp, jooq

I have a table with integer values on how often something should occur:

```
my_table.frequency(Integer)
my_table.last_run(Timestamp)
```

What I want is to add last run with frequency to check if it is less than or greater than current time.

This has to be done in JOOQ.

This is basically what I'm trying to do.

```java
dsl.selectFrom(FTP_CONFIGURATIONS)                
   .where(FTP_CONFIGURATIONS.DIRECTION.eq("FROM")   
   .and(DSL.timestampAdd(
       FTP_CONFIGURATIONS.LAST_RUN,
       FTP_CONFIGURATIONS.FREQUENCY.div(1000)), DatePart.SECOND)
   .lessOrEqual(DSL.currentTimestamp())))                
   .orderBy(FTP_CONFIGURATIONS.ID.desc())
```

I'm not getting what I need from this. Why I do not know since I have no idea how tho check the generated sql????

Comment: If your integer encodes "how often", then it is not a timestamp - it is an [Interval](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.7/manual/reference/reference-data-types/data-types-intervals/). You should treat it so.

Comment: A sound statement and probably very true unfortunately I lack influence over the DB to be able to change anything. If you mean that I should rethink  my approach. Then I missed your point could you please specify?

Comment: Does the add operation have to be done in the database? What if you just get those values and do the math in your Java code? You could use the built-in [`Duration` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html) for that, if you're using Java 8 (for Java <= 7, there's also the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), which has a [similar class](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Duration.html))

Comment: @PlickPlick, I don't mean that you should change your database schema. What I mean is you should convert your field to appropriate `Interval`, such as `YearToMonth` or `DayToSecond` in JOOQ's query builder (assuming this conversion is supported at this time).

Comment: Also see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18398849/7470253) helps.

Comment: You are definitely on the right track! And I was missunderstandings you at first. My integer value are in milliseconds how should I create a DayToSecond object the constructor only taking seconds or nanoseconds. I'm missing a fundamental part here about understanding how jooq works. I have not had time to properly read through the documentation. Could you please fill in the blanks? Hopefully you know what I'm only guessing at. I have tried to get access to the value to manipulate it to nano or second but I'm not able to. My understanding are lacking a great deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dsl.selectFrom(FTP_CONFIGURATIONS)                .where(FTP_CONFIGURATIONS.DIRECTION.eq("FROM")
.and(DSL.timestampAdd(FTP_CONFIGURATIONS.LAST_RUN,FTP_CONFIGURATIONS.FREQUENCY.div(1000)),DatePart.SECOND)
.lessOrEqual(DSL.currentTimestamp())))                .orderBy(FTP_CONFIGURATIONS.ID.desc())`

This is actually the answer but I should not take credit for it. It was M. Prokhorov who lead me to it suggesting I should use Interval.

The reason I could not get it to work was old walues in last_run.